# How to update attributes using Cognito if user is not confirmed?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to update user attributes if the user is not signed in using AuthenticationHandler nor is that user confirmed? The idea is that for when an user registers their account, and before "confirming" their account that user changes their email to a different email address. I have tried to use UpdateAttributesHandler, but I receive exceptions.

(1) If, for the user object, I use userpool.getCurrentUser() or userpool.getUser(), I receive the following exception:

```
W/System.err: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoNotAuthorizedException: User-ID is null
```

(2) if, for the user object, I use userpool.getUser(""), I receive the following exception:

```
W/System.err: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoNotAuthorizedException: user is not authenticated
```

(3) if, for the user object, I user userpool.getUser(""), I receive the following exception:

```
W/System.err: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoNotAuthorizedException: user is not authenticated
```

My implementation is the following:

```
       user = userPool.getCurrentUser();
       UpdateAttributesHandler handler = new UpdateAttributesHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails> list) {
                     // set listener
                mOnCognitoUpdateUserAttributesListener.onSuccess(list);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                // resend code failed
                Log.e(TAG, exception.toString());
                // set listener
                mOnCognitoUpdateUserAttributesListener.onFailure(exception);
            }
        };
        user.updateAttributesInBackground(userAttributes, handler);
```

This request fails every time with the exceptions I have expressed before. What is missing in being able to update the users' information? This is not mentioned in AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Maybe your user is signed out, but userPool.getCurrentUser(); is giving you the cached user... so try signing in again

Comment: ...where you able to solve this? I am having similar errors.

Comment: I was not able to solve this problem, however, I was able to receive an answer. I opened a ticket with AWS technical support and they said that the user MUST be verified first in order to do functionalities like change password, forget password, signin, and change user attributes.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to specify email as required in your schema.  Provision the user server side using AdminCreateUser and have the password sent to the user via SMS.  When the user logs in for the first time, they must set their email.